# Android recycled bitmap error

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, recycle

I'm goning to resize bitmap and insert into imageView.

However I encountered recycle error...

error message :

`05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792): 
Process: com.test.myapp, PID: 4792
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@2f1aa6ad
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1225)
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:600)
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:544)
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792):     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1187)
05-08 13:32:48.948: E/AndroidRuntime(4792):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16209)`

**Could you give an advice how to resolve my situation..**

My Code :

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(full_path);
SaveBitmapToFileCache(photo, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test/"+filename);

imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

private Bitmap getBitmapSize(Bitmap photo){
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bmp = photo;
    Bitmap resizeBmp = null;
    if(bmp.getWidth() > 2000 || bmp.getHeight() > 2000)
        resizeBmp = resizingBitmap(mContext, bmp, bmp.getWidth()/10 , bmp.getHeight()/10, false);
    else if(bmp.getWidth() > 1000 || bmp.getHeight() > 1000)
        resizeBmp = resizingBitmap(mContext, bmp, bmp.getWidth()/5 , bmp.getHeight()/5, false);
    else
        resizeBmp = resizingBitmap(mContext, bmp, bmp.getWidth() , bmp.getHeight(), false);

    resizeBmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os);
    bmp.recycle();

    return resizeBmp;
}

private void SaveBitmapToFileCache(Bitmap bitmap, String strFilePath) {
    File fileCacheItem = new File(strFilePath);
    OutputStream out = null;

    try{
        fileCacheItem.createNewFile();
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileCacheItem);

        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I meet recycle error?

Answer (score 0):

***Use these lines of code..***

```
if(resizeBmp !=null)
{
  resizeBmp .recycle();
  bmp.recycle();
  bmp=null;
  resizeBmp =null;
}
```